# Youtube API 3.0 - Obtainaining Youtube Share Counter & All Youtube comments for channel

Tags: youtube-api

My Total Life Time shares on youtube is 862 How do I retrieve this data? https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ < I believe I start it like this, right?

How do I retrieve ALL COMMENTS for my channel. (Not for a single video) https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Z3M.jpg On my Dashboard, it lists all my recent comments. How do I retrieve this data? https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ < I believe I start it like this, right? (Not worried about the filtered comments if it's trickier)

I plan on using OBS to display my total share count & my latest comment(s) If PHP is involved, would I need a website? Or can I run PHP from my computer?

I believe I understand how to get an API key, but feel free to explain this part to.

I'm hoping coding is not needed, just to get the data. RIght now, only looking to retrieve the data, and if I can do PHP locally for OBS studio!

If there's something you're confused about, ask me questions. I need a direction please!

Answer (score 0):

> My Total Life Time shares on youtube is 862 How do I retrieve this data? https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ < I believe I start it like this, right?

Yup great place to start.

> How do I retrieve ALL COMMENTS for my channel. (Not for a single video) https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Z3M.jpg On my Dashboard, it lists all my recent comments. How do I retrieve this data? https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ < I believe I start it like this, right? (Not worried about the filtered comments if it's trickier)

Again good place to start.

> I plan on using OBS to display my total share count & my latest comment(s) If PHP is involved, would I need a website? Or can I run PHP from my computer?

Yes you can run php locally on your machine without a website.  You can access the API in any language capable of preforming a HTTP Post and HTTP get.

> I believe I understand how to get an API key, but feel free to explain this part to.

Api key will only help you get public data if you want your own private data you are going to need to look into Oauth2

> I'm hoping coding is not needed, just to get the data. RIght now, only looking to retrieve the data, and if I can do PHP locally for OBS studio!

PHP is a scripting language.  Coding is going to be required here to access the api and again to process the raw data that is returned.

If there's something you're confused about, ask me questions. I need a direction please!

Comment: So, OBS browser source can run a PHP file? And before I can see my Share counter, I have to do PHP Oauth2 first?

Comment: if you are doing oauth2 then you need a browser

Comment: Which means OBS share counter is impossible (good to know, before wasting my time)